# creating a binary file, adding info to it, and reading all records from it (phonebook)

Tags: c++, file, binary

i would like to thank you for your great support. i gotta admit that c++ is fun and is pretty amazing, but sometimes it becomes a pain in the head. ive been trying to solve this homework.. its almost done, but im having some hard time trying to figure out how to work with binary files.

the question is the following:

> You have been hired to help program a new "Ma Bell" telephone feature.
>   The feature allows users with "PC" to obtain a disk of telephone
>   numbers in addition to a telephone book. Your job is to write the
>   program which will allow the phone information to be used.  You must
>   allow the addition of and viewing of phone number information.
>
> The program should be able to:
>    1. Add people to the telephone list
>    2. View all people in the list
>    3. View based on just the last name
>
> You may make the following assumptions:
>
> ```
> 1. There are no more than 100 phone numbers
> 2. No name is longer than 50 characters.
> 3. Only one telephone number per person.
> 4. The address should be broken into only
>      street # or PO Box
>      street name
>      zip code
> ```

the code i wrote is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class phonebook
{
private: char fname[25];
         char lname[25];
         char tel[10];
         int pobox;
         char street[20];
         int zipcode;
         int id;

public: phonebook(char[]=" ",char[]=" ",char[]=" ",int=0,char[]=" ",int=0,int=0);
        void setfname(char*);
        void setlname(char*);
        void settel(char*);
        char* getfname();
        char* getlname();
        char* gettel();
        void setpobox(int);
        void setstreet(char*);
        void setzipcode(int);
        int getpobox();
        char* getstreet();
        int getzipcode();
        void setid(int);
        int getid();
};

phonebook::phonebook(char* fn,char* ln, char* t,int p,char* s, int z,int i)
{
    setfname(fn);
    setlname(ln);
    settel(t);
    setpobox(p);
    setstreet(s);
    setzipcode(z);
    setid(i);
}
void phonebook::setfname(char* fn){strcpy(fname,fn);}
void phonebook::setlname(char* ln){strcpy(lname,ln);}
void phonebook::settel(char* t){strcpy(tel,t);}
char* phonebook::getfname(){return fname;}
char* phonebook::getlname(){return lname;}
char* phonebook::gettel(){return tel;}
void phonebook::setpobox(int p){pobox=p;}
void phonebook::setstreet(char* s){strcpy(street,s);}
void phonebook::setzipcode(int z){zipcode=z;}
int phonebook::getpobox(){return pobox;}
char* phonebook::getstreet(){return street;}
int phonebook::getzipcode(){return zipcode;}
void phonebook::setid(int i){id=i;}
int phonebook::getid(){return id;}

int main()
{
    phonebook pb;
    fstream outfile("phonebook.dat",ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(!outfile){cerr<<"file could not be created!";exit(1);}

    //for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        //outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&pb),sizeof(phonebook));


         char FN[25];
         char LN[25];
         char T[10];
         int P;
         char S[20];
         int Z;
         int x;
         int id;
         cout<<"Choose one of the following: "<<endl;
         cout<<"1. Add people to the telephone list"<<endl;
         cout<<"2. View all people in the list"<<endl;
         cout<<"3. View based on just the last name"<<endl;
         cin>>x;

         switch(x)
         {
         case 1:
         cout<<"Enter record number, first name, last name, telephone, pobox, street, zipcode: "<<endl;
         cin>>id>>FN>>LN>>T>>P>>S>>Z;
         pb.setid(id);
         pb.setfname(FN);
         pb.setlname(LN);
         pb.settel(T);
         pb.setpobox(P);
         pb.setstreet(S);
         pb.setzipcode(Z);
         outfile.seekp((id-1)*sizeof(phonebook));
         outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&pb),sizeof(pb));break;

         case 2:
             for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    outfile.seekg((i-1)*sizeof(phonebook));
                    cout<<pb.getfname()<<" "<<pb.getlname()<<" "<<pb.gettel()<<" "<<pb.getpobox()<<" "<<pb.getstreet()<<" "<<pb.getzipcode()<<endl;}break;

         case 3:

      cout<<"Enter last name: ";
      cin>>LN;
      outfile.seekp((id-1)*sizeof(phonebook));
      outfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pb),sizeof(pb));
         if((strcmp(pb.getlname(),LN)==0))
         cout<<pb.getfname()<<" "<<pb.getlname()<<" "<<pb.gettel()<<" "<<pb.getpobox()<<" "<<pb.getstreet()<<" "<<pb.getzipcode()<<endl;
         else cout<<"name not found!"<<endl;break;
         }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when i want to list the info i added to the binary file, its not reading. I'm only getting zeros. also i would like to know how to make the switch statement to ask me if i want to either add more phone numbers or like a loop for the switch cases. 
also, how can i make the program to search for a name inside the binary file. i tried my best but i just cant make it work.

Comment: Just a small comment: **Never hide the `break` statements in your `switch` statements on the same line as other code.** In general, one-statement-per-line is definitely the best approach, but `break` statements must stand out clearly.

Comment: Are the zeros you're getting accurate? If you view your binary file with a hex editor or hex viewer (`xxd(1)` is an excellent choice if you're new to the idea of hex viewers) do you see the data you expect or do you see a big pile of nothing?

Comment: I'm going to recommend you throw out archaic C-style naming conventions. Lack of "camelhumps" also makes reading token names more difficult. Most editors have auto-completion or at least copy-paste functionality. The cost of a readability far outweighs the few characters you are saving with shorthand.

What is `fname`? What is `lname`? What is `tel`? I can *guess* these things in this very small, limited context. FirstName, LastName, TelephoneNumber. What if this program evolved into actually communicating with a telephone? What if I assumed `settel` set a Telephony device abstraction object?

Comment: As a sidenote is there any particular reason you are using `char*` instead of `std::string`? Seems like an unnecessary headache.

Answer (score 2):

Thou shalt verify thy file operation succeed! Hint: if you actually want a fighting chance for a write operation to be successful, you might want to consider opening the file write mode. As it stands, I would be surprised if you ever manage to write to the input file.

Comment: @LebTech where does it go wrong then? Since you checked all your I/O operations you should have a better handle on where there is a problem then "didn't work" and we may be able to give you concrete help.